# Passing a callback object from parent to child component angular

Tags: angular, callback, lifecycle

I have a form component which is parent and a show-results component which is child component.
I make an a call to an api and I have to use a callback to retrieve the data.
In my service layer I make my call:

```
postSearchDocument(response: any, callback): void {
  console.log('Response form in service layer: ', response);

  const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open('POST', this.appConfig.getConfig().apiUrl + '' + this.appConfig.getConfig().searchDocument, true);

  // build SOAP request
  const soapRequest =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
    '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
    'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
    'xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ' +
    'xmlns:bran="http://www.bottomline.com/soap/branch/">' +
    '<soapenv:Header/>' +
    '<soapenv:Body>' +
    '<bran:CallBranch soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' +
    '<JSONRequest xsi:type="xsd:string">' +
    JSON.stringify(response) +
    '</JSONRequest>' +
    '</bran:CallBranch>' +
    '</soapenv:Body>' +
    '</soapenv:Envelope>';

  console.log('SOAP REQUEST ');
  console.log(soapRequest.toString());

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
      if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        this.returnValue = xmlhttp.responseText;
        // alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        console.log('Response : ');
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);

        this.documentResponse = JSON.parse(this.returnValue)
      );  
      console.log(this.documentResponse);
      callback.apply(this, [this.documentResponse]);
      // return this.documentResponse;
    }
  }
};
```

Obviously I pass data from parent to children :

```
<app-show-results [documentsResponse]="documentsResponse"></app-show-results>
```

In the parent component I have a onSubmit method that allow me to make a call to my API:

```
this.apiService.postSearchDocument(this.searchRequest, this.getResponse);
```

Here is my callback :

```
getResponse(response): void {
  this.documentsResponse = response;
  console.log('In callback response ', this.documentsResponse);
}
```

This API call is using SOAP and I added a callback in order to get the response back from the server :

In my child component I do have this variable :

```
@Input() documentsResponse;
```

My issue is that i don't display the return value from parent in the child component. I added in my child component a lifecycle hook to monitor changes :

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): Promise<any> {
  if (changes.documentsResponse && this.documentsResponse !== null) {
    console.log(this.documentsResponse);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does postSearchDocument look like..?

Comment: What type of `changeDetectionStrategy` you are using? in the parent and child components?

Comment: Can you also post parent and child typescript code? to check exact issue

Comment: I guess i'm using default changeDetectionStrategy ... i didn't set any thing like this. I updated the code

Comment: Can you add code that you have inside @Component() decorators

Comment: In the parent i added : changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush.. I also set a private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef in the parent constructor.

Comment: Yeah, that is the issue ;)

Comment: but i am stuck on how to say to my child component that my data arrived in the parent

Comment: Just need another snippet, how is your callback function looks like?

Comment: My callback is getResponse(response) method

Comment: @davidvera did the answer resolved your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` change detection will be limited and applicable to some situations only. You need to mark Parent component and child components for check in the next cycle. Try below code

**Parent Component**

```
import { ..., ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'

@Component({})
class ParentComponent {
  documentResponse: any

  ...

  constructor(
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ...

  getResponse(response) {
    this.documentResponse = response;
    this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck(); // Here is the fix
  }
}
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-cds-op-skt?file=src/app/app.component.ts)